# AngularJS: why is $scope undefined inside my ES6 controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to AngularJS so the answer to this question might be obvious, but I'm stuck on it.

In my component, I have the following code (I've simplified it for the question):

```
class $controller {
  constructor($scope, Vote) {
    $scope.isRunning = false;
    this.Vote = Vote;
  }

  switchVote(user){
    $scope.isRunning = true;
    if (appUser.vote) {
      var vote = new this.Vote({userId: user.id});
      vote.delete().then(function() {
        user.vote = null;
        $scope.isRunning = false;
      })
    }
     else {
      this.componentThing.createVote(user).then(function(vote) {
        user.vote = vote.id;
        $scope.isRunning = false;
      })
    }
  }
}
```

In the HTML I have an `ng-disabled="isRunning"` on the button that allows vote creation and destruction. The idea is to prevent multiple requests from piling up if the user clicks twice before the ajax request is completed.

My problem is that $scope is undefined in my switchVote() method. Why is it undefined even though I initialized it in the constructor?

Comment: I haven't used AngularJS with ES6 but I think you need to bind scope in constructor : this.$scope = $scope

Comment: If you are using ES6 classes, you should avoid using $scope and instantiate controllers with `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: Also use fat-arrow functions instead of old style anonymous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$scope` is only visible within the constructor function. You need to assign it to an accessor on `this` so you have access to it within other functions.

```
constructor($scope, Vote) {
   this.$scope = $scope;
   this.$scope.isRunning = true;
   ...
}

switchVote(user){
   this.$scope.isRunning = true;
   ...
}
```

Comment: This fixes my problem! Thanks so much!